# iOS voicemail app/code when provider doesn't offer voicemail

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit, voicemail

My provider (Singtel - prepaid) does not offer voicemail. I feel like it should be possible through iOS' CallKit to autoanswer any call, play a message and record (ideally also transcribe) the message that is left.

I don't mind coding up something, however, ideally something like this exists. Before I look into coding something. Any advise on the feasibility or functions to use?

Comment: CallKit can be used to create VoIP apps that can interact with some elements of the native phone app (missed calls can appear in the phone missed call list, and the phone will know you are on a VoIP call when a cell call arrives and provide call waiting or diversion depending on your settings). It is not possible for an app to answer or intercept the audio path of cellular calls

Comment: That's too bad! No other way?